# Video continua a reproduzir quando a modal fecha

Tags: javascript, api, modal, iframe, youtube

Criei uma modal que abre ao clicar numa imagem, dentro dessa modal terá um video do youtube e um pequena descrição do lado, no entanto sempre que fecho a modal o video continua a reproduzir. Queria que o video pausasse ao clicar em fechar e (se possível) começasse a reproduzir sozinho ao abrir a modal. Já tentei vários códigos Java mas parece que por algum motivo nenhum funciona com o meu código.

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
 <script>

  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '365,99',
      width: '650',
      videoId: 'd0D8tTtY4lU',

    });

$(".text").on("click", function() {
player.playVideo();
});
  }


</script>

</head>

<body>

<a href="#abrirmodal"><div class="container"><img class="image" 
src="https://cdn.flickeringmyth.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Paddington-2-
posters-1-header.jpg" alt="Paddington 2 - Trailer" ><div class="middle">
<div class="text"><img src="play.png" alt="play" width="60" height="60">
</div>
</div></div></a>   

<div id="abrirmodal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<table border="1">
<a href="#fechar" title="Fechar" class="fechar">x</a>

<tr>
<td ROWSPAN="2">  <div id="player"></div>
</div> </td>
<td><h2>Modal</h2></td></tr>
<tr><td>Esta é uma simples janela de modal.
Você pode fazer qualquer coisa aqui, página de Login, pop-ups, ou 
formulários.</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Já tentei utilizar o link iframe do Youtube em vez da API, mas também não consegui. A função:

```
$(".text").on("click", function() {
player.playVideo();
});
```

Também parece não funcionar, tanto para começar a reprodução como para pausar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código tem muitos problemas. Como não dá para analisar completamente porque me parece que ele depende de alguns estilos e códigos não listados na pergunta, vou colocar um simples exemplo baseado no código postado.

Tanto o código `player.playVideo();` quanto `player.stopVideo();` funciona normalmente. Provavelmente não está funcionando porque não está colocando no lugar certo ou chamando de forma correta ([info sobre a API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=pt-br)).

**[Veja um exemplo do seu código em funcionamento no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jz9h2sj7/)** (a API não funciona aqui no snippet):

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
   player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '365,99',
      width: '650',
      videoId: 'd0D8tTtY4lU',
   });
}

$("a").on("click", function() {
   $("table").show();
   player.playVideo();
});

$(".fechar").on("click", function(e) {
   $("table").hide();
   player.stopVideo();
});
```

```css
table{
   position: fixed;
   top: 10px;
   left: 0;
   background: white;
   display: none;
}

.fechar{
   padding: 10px;
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#abrirmodal">
   <div class="container">
      <img class="image" src="https://cdn.flickeringmyth.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Paddington-2-posters-1-header.jpg" alt="Paddington 2 - Trailer" >
   </div>
</a>   

<div id="abrirmodal" class="modalDialog"><div>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td ROWSPAN="2">
         <div id="player"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <a href="#fechar" title="Fechar" class="fechar">x</a>
         <h2>Modal</h2>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         Esta é uma simples janela de modal.
         Você pode fazer qualquer coisa aqui, página de Login, pop-ups, ou formulários.
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Copiei o código exatamente como me enviou. No entanto ele continua a não funcionar. Ao clicar na imagem, a tabela não abre. Não entendo realmente porque, uma vez que o código está a funcionar corretamente no JSFiddle. Mas sempre que clico na imagem, o link muda (por exemplo passa de index.html para index.html#abrirmodal) mas nada acontece. Vou deixar aqui em baixo uma resposta com o código exatamente como ele está no momento.

Comment: @DianaTaveira Vc carregou o jQuery no início do <head>?

Comment: @DianaTaveira Outra coisa, o <script> dever ir depois dos elementos, no final do <body>.

Comment: sim, mas não obtive nenhum resultado por isso tentei carregar também no final do body, mas continuou sem funcionar. O Código jQuery que utilizei foi este: 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @DianaTaveira Vou mudar o Fiddle, deve estar havendo algum conflito.

Comment: consegui, era isso mesmo, foi só colocar o script no final do body! muito obrigada

Comment: @DianaTaveira Legal. Obg!

Comment: deparei-me agora com outro problema. no codigo java a função abrir é definida por "a" e mostra a "table". No entanto eu pretendo fazer 4 imagens diferentes a abrir 4 tabelas diferentes com 4 videos diferentes. No entanto com este código todas as imagens abrem a mesma janela. Há alguma forma de colocar class ou id em vez de "a" e "table"?

Comment: @DianaTaveira Sim. Vc pode colocar um id para cada vídeo e pegar isso pelo clique.

Answer (score 0):

No momento o meu código está assim:

```
<head>

<title>Efeito Modal</title>
<style>
table{
position: fixed;
top: 10px;
left: 0;
background: white;
display: none;
}

.fechar{
padding: 10px;
background: yellow;
}

.image{
width: 320px;
height: 180px;
}
</style>

<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('player', {
  height: '165,99',
  width: '250',
  videoId: 'd0D8tTtY4lU',
});
}

$("a").on("click", function() {
$("table").show();
player.playVideo();
});

$(".fechar").on("click", function(e) {
$("table").hide();
player.stopVideo();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#abrirmodal">

  <img class="image" src="https://cdn.flickeringmyth.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/05/Paddington-2-posters-1-header.jpg" alt="Paddington 2 
- Trailer" >

</a>   

<div id="abrirmodal" class="modalDialog"><div>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
    <td ROWSPAN="2">
     <div id="player"></div>
  </td>
  <td>
     <a href="#fechar" title="Fechar" class="fechar">x</a>
     <h2>Modal</h2>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     Esta é uma simples janela de modal.
     Você pode fazer qualquer coisa aqui, página de Login, pop-ups, ou 
formulários.
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

   </body>
```